# values-21, values-22 or values-xx folder is gone after Android Studio 1.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-styles

When I create a new project with API14 as minimum, then there is no `values-21` or `values-22` folder in my project. I don't see any styles.XML anywhere, so how should I put in XML code for just Lollipop?

I use Android Studio 1.0.1, and I have SDK 21, 21.1.1, 24.0.2 installed.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Updated**: Since `API 22` has been released. `API 23` is the same idea.

Right click the `RES` folder

[image]

Then type `values-v22` as the directory name and choose xml as the resource type.

[image]

If you do NOT see the `values-v22` show up, `click` the Project pulldown at the top of the screen like so. e.g. Change from Android to Project

[image]

Now right click `styles.xml` in the `values folder` and choose copy

[image]

Now right click the `values-v22` folder and click paste.

[image]

You should see this popup

[image]

Click `ok`

At this point you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks bjiang.

<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_dark</item> dont have any problem in styles.xml in v21 folder while in the regular styles it says that I have min api14, so its correct.

Comment: @bjiang,  
 
i get Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar' in res/values-v21/styles.xml, and in <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar"> </style> plz help

Comment: @PankajNimgade I think that because you lost `themes_material.xml` for some reason, you can get it from [here](https://gist.github.com/jbj88817/b0a3f750e3fe705a8a1a) and create a `xml file` named `themes_material.xml`, put the `file under the folder` of `sdk/platforms/android-21/data/res/values/`

Comment: @bjiang, I have this file "themes_material.xml" in respective directory. I really don't know what else to do. in styles.xml i can't write any resource which starts with "android:"

Answer (score 2):

It is just a bug! Anyway I find a way to get it back:

1. Write anything in *styles.xml* that is related to new material theme 
   example: `<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>`
2. It will show you an error hover over it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. choose the first choice Override Resource in values-v21.

I know it isn't the best way to do that, but it works until anyone can find a better way.

Comment: Temporary faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch from `Android` to `[![Project][1]][1]` as shown below

[image]